# How to activate listeners in renderer function in a grid column

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4 and I have a grid which shows a field name Approval. Here I have showed checkbox that will be checked when the grid is loaded if the value is true. But if the dataIndex value is fault only the checkbox will appear. Now I want that if I click on unchecked checkbox it will do a action using listeners. But I am not being able to do it. Can anyone please help me on this ? My codes are given below :

```
{
   text: 'Approval',
   dataIndex: 'approve',
   flex: 1,
   align: 'left',
   renderer: function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView){
    if(value == true)
      {
        return '<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />';
      }else{
        return '<input type = "checkbox"  />';
         listeners: {
            this.approve();
          }
       }
     }   
  }

approve: function(){
        alert('hi');
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

### Old answer

The checkbox has a [change](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-event-change) listener which will get fired after the value has changed.

```
{
        xtype     : 'checkbox'
        boxLabel  : 'This is my checkbox',
        name      : 'mycheckbox',
        inputValue: true,
        listeners : {
              change: function(cbx, newValue, oldValue){
                     me.approve();
              }
        }
}
```

Note that you can't use `this` inside the listener because the function gets called inside another scope.

## Edit:

Start using a [`Ext.ux.CheckColumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.CheckColumn) on your grid.

Now you can use:

```
{ 
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    text: 'Approval',
    dataIndex: 'approve',
    flex: 1,
    align: 'left',
    sortable: false,
    listeners:{
        checkchange:function(cc,ix,isChecked){
            alert(isChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this may work for only xtype:'checkbox' . All I need here is to use listener with the return statement. Cause when my unchecked checkbox will be clicked an action will occur. So can you help on this ? mention that all my work is in renderer.

Comment: You can't add listeners to a non extjs object. Use the HTML equivalent: `<input type='checkbox' onchange='gotChanged(this);'>`

Comment: Or you can use `Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {config});`

Comment: I have used 'var a = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox',{});                               return a;' but it returns in the grid like this 'object Object]' not checkbox

Comment: well done :) +1 You should be able to take criticism and not start right away and downvote these peoples by yourself. There's a reason why I write this in the comment.

Comment: Can we discuss this elsewhere? Ty for your review.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to archive is not possible out of the box.

I guess you want to display the checkbox all the time? Otherwise the **[CellEditor](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing)** Plugin is already what you are looking for.

But it should anyway the point to start (I guess). Here is a example code the uses ExtJS classes & images to display a sort of fake combo in a cell along with a celleditior. There is one think you still have to fix; you need to override the cellcontent before the edits starts cause the celleditor seems to remove only default types.

**Way going this way?** Of course you could modify the checkbox with a unique id and fetch the Ext.Element for it which would now enable you to register events. But that approach has one downside, you need to care about render time otherwise your combos does not exist when you are trying to fetch it. Therefore I recommend you this approach. It you be quite easy to wipe the image before the rendering starts.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":true},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":false},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":true},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":true}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1},
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone',
         editor: { xtype: 'checkbox', inputValue: 'true', uncheckedValue: 'false' }, renderer: function(value){ 
             return value ? '<span class="x-form-cb-checked"><div class="x-form-checkbox"></div></span>' : '<div class="x-form-checkbox"></div>';  
         }
  }
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVQGh/)**

Comment: That just looks weird. I wouldn't go for this from a user perspective. But it works.

Comment: @JohanHaest Well, it will be usable for grids with even very huge amount of records without any performance issues. I've done something similar in the past with ExtJS3

Comment: I'm saying it has performance issues, but if suddenly a second checkbox pops up the user doesn't know which one to click. Besides that it works great, and thats why I upvoted...

Comment: @JohanHaest My answer was just a side-info. And you can get rid of that one. You need to register to the before edit event an cleanup the cell. The renderer will be called anyway after edit. At least this worked in the past for me